# Predefined Menu Item in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have been fiddling around with Visual Studio and have been able to add buttons/toolbar menus and the different configurations.

I was wondering if there is anyway to add a custom item to the menu?

[image]

Just anywhere within the dropdown we get when we right click a method/string/whatever.

Is this possible? If so, where do I start?

Cheers!

Comment: Use the code snippets functionality: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Customize -> (tab sheet) Commands and use the context menu radio button. In the drop down you can select which context menu you want to change. The one you are refering to is the one selected in this picture "Editor Context Menus | Code Window".

[image: Go to tools->customize]

Add your commands directly or if you want to add a new sub menu then use the "add sub menu" button and change the selection within the drop down to the specific sub menu afterwards. There you can create again sub menus or commands. I created the SVN on the picture for example.

[image: showing self created sub menu]

Here is what it looks like to me:
[image]